# How to define a variable to link my google sheets in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, google-sheets-api, tkinter-entry

I'm learning **Tkinter** and i worked in a login interface, i have two *entries* for my *username and password**, also one button for my **login**, I've defined a function for my entries and login button with sqlite database and it works good locally, but I want to store my usernames and passwords in a server so i choose to use Google sheets API in order to create a sheet and store there my usernames and passwords, I triede to define a funtion to link my entries and login button but it does'nt work. any advise thanks in advance. have a good day.

```
#THIS IS MY FUNCTION PART

def logear():

    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("testsheetsxxxxx.json", scope)

    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    sheet = client.open("testing").sheet1    ########'testisng is my google sheet and 'sheet1' is what im 
                                                      using to store usernames and passwords###########

    user = entry_usuario.get()              ####entry_usuario is my username entry########
    contra = entry_contrasena.get()         ####entry_contrasena us my password entry######

    c = #####stucked here####

    if ####stucked here####:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='login correcto', message='usuario y contraseña correctos')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Contraseña Incorrecta')
```

Comment: I dont quite understand, what is the problem your facing?

Comment: @CoolCloud I don't know how to define my function 'logear' in order to link it with my entries and login button, I'm using Google sheets API to store my 'usernames' and 'passwords'

Comment: How are you retrieving the username and password.

Comment: @CoolCloud i've defined `c= sheet.get_all_records()` , in my sheet1 i have two columns username and password, before I was using sqlite3 and it worked well locally, but now I'm using Google sheets API and I'm stucked defining **def logear():**

Comment: What does `print(c)` give?

Comment: @CoolCloud `[{'password': 1111, 'username': 'user1'},
 {'password': 2222, 'username': 'user2'},
 {'password': 3333, 'username': 'user3'}]`

Comment: Isnt that what you want? Loop through the dictionary, check if username exists inside the dictionary then fetch its password and check if it is the password fetched.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, but once I run my login interface in Tkinter, I enter my username and password, push the login button but it doesn't work, I'm defining wrongly my button command **def logear():**

Comment: Notice how the the usernames are `int`, I recommend storing an `str` as username. Or change your storing as `{'111':'user1','2222':'user2'}`

Comment: @CoolCloud before this worker fine for me with sqlite3                                            `def logear():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('login_file.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    user = entry_usuario.get()
    contra = entry_contrasena.get()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM superusuario WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ?', (user, contra))

    if c.fetchall():
        messagebox.showinfo(title='login correcto', message='usuario y contraseña correctos')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Contraseña Incorrecta')

    c.close()`

Comment: Obviously SQLite and google sheets aren't same.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yeh, you're right buddy, that's why I was looking for a server to store deploy my sqlite database, but I couldn't find any , so I'm trying to use Google sheets API but having issues defining my button command =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

```
def logear():
    # Rest of required code 
    user = entry_usuario.get() 
    contra = entry_contrasena.get()
    for i in c: # Loop through the list
        if int(user) == i['contraseña'] and contra == i['password']:  # Check if password and username exists in the dict
            messagebox.showinfo(title='login correcto', message='usuario y contraseña correctos')
            break
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Detalles incorrectos')
```

Here the only problem I see is, username always have to be an `int`, so I recommend changing it to `str` so that its more efficient.

I dont know why you switched from SQLite to Google Sheets both will be insecure as you are storing passwords as plaintext, I recommend hashing it pre-hand and storing the hashed values. And as far as hosting of a database is concerned there are other online servers which allow MySQL database to be hosted, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205019/13382000)

Comment: thanks man!, it's working better now, when i enter an username it's working good but i think the password entry isn't working, even entering a right username and wrong password it shows 'correct username and password'

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I typed the code by hand, it should be `and` instead of `or`, I updated my answer, try again.

Comment: it's working pretty good now man, but I'm not taking `int` for `int(user)` , and i was using `and` since always, I just realized why my **password** wasn't working properly it's because in my sheets it was numbers and for some reason my tkinter entry isn't getting it, even modify my sheet and give it a "text without format" and not only a "number format" isn't working at all, but it's ok I can use alphanumeric password, I really apreciate the time you took for helping me man, have a good day!

Comment: I forgot something man! Once my login username and password are correct I want to open a new tkinter file **mainformuser.py** should I use my `def logear ():` function or define a new function with the same button?, I tried this , after `if int(user) == i['contraseña'] and contra == i['password']:` I used `else:             mainformuser.pack` psdt: first I've imported **mainformuser**

Comment: Is `mainformuser` a widget? Why using `pack()` in it? It is better to ask a new question here for detailed help in this.

Comment: it was my mistake man, it is `mainformuser.py ` , alright, I'm gonna ask new question, thanks