# How to limit user's connections in my Tkinter program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, google-sheets

I have a small interface in Tkinter. I wonder whether there is a way to limit its connections per computer. I'm using google sheets API to control the users and passwords, so I want it to be used once account per computer. Any idea thanks in advance guys!

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing code and what exactly you mean, and `I'm using google sheets API to control the users and passwords, so I want it to be used once account per computer.` does not sound like a robust infrastructured geared towards user experience and security.

Comment: @BijayRegmi It's a small project and all database is stored locally (so nothing about user sercurity is compromised), the username and password are just used to go into the interface. Anyway thanks for your advise, I'll take it.

Comment: Not sure how the data from google sheet is returned, but you can get the IP address and store it, and check if the IP address already exists, while making an account.

Comment: @CoolCloud Hello mate!, I was thinking about IP or MAC this is the link for the code you've solved before, I'm using Google sheets API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246996/how-to-define-a-variable-to-link-my-google-sheets-in-tkinter/66247710?noredirect=1#comment117170524_66247710

Comment: How do you store data on the google sheet? Your create an account function.

Comment: @CoolCloud I have two columns in my google sheets (username and password), I just have to edit manually the values in my sheet to add or delete an accout. That's all my login form does.

Comment: So there is no 'create_an_account' function? You are doing it manually? Then why would you want to limit one account per PC, you will be knowing to not make an account as you are manually doing it, not the program.

Comment: @CoolCloud So there is no way right?, I just thought after entering the correct username and password there could be a way to validate the IP or MAC address in order to open the main form.

Comment: If you store their IP address somewhere along with login details, then yes.

Comment: @CoolCloud I'll search about that, I have an issue, I wonder if you know why my program doesn't work in my laptop, I'm trying to login with it seems that there is no connection at all for my loginForm, It works fine with my other desktops (windows 10) but with my laptop is not working, it has windows 8 , I formated it and install windows 10 supossing it was the issue but isnt working, any idea mate?

Comment: I am not sure how the connection to this API works, but it should be able to run from any PC. If it works from other desktops and not just this one, it means you are maybe making some mistake in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230550/discussion-between-paul-and-cool-cloud).